# Can't succeed in making transparent window in Electron (javascript)

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to make a transparent window with ElectronJs but I obtain a black background.

I am on Linux (Debian Jessie)

I have tried different versions : latest, beta and nightly with the same result.

I have a version for NW.js that works on the same machine, so I expect it is a Electron problem.

Here is my code of `main.js`:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
let mainWindow;
function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 920, height: 300,  frame:true, transparent:true, backgroundColor: '#00FFFFFF'});
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}
app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

Here is my code of `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0); color:lightgrey;">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <!-- All of the Node.js APIs are available in this renderer process. -->
    We are using Node.js <script>document.write(process.versions.node)</script>,
    Chromium <script>document.write(process.versions.chrome)</script>,
    and Electron <script>document.write(process.versions.electron)</script>.

    <script>
      // You can also require other files to run in this process
      // require('./renderer.js')
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that background is not transparent but black :

[image]

Have tried different things without success (for example `app.disableHardwareAcceleration()`)

**Does someone knows the solution or have a full working example ?**

Thx

-

Edit 1 :
Have also tried with and without `--enable-transparent-visuals --disable-gpu`
as said [here](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's a very old regression bug in Electron project.

See https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/15947

To bypass that problem, just downgrade to <s>`1.4.16`</s> `2.0.16`, the last working version.

---

EDIT 1 : if you wait at least 300ms after ready event to open windows it will work correctly

```
app.on('ready', () => setTimeout(onAppReady, 300));
```

And you do not need `--disable-gpu` option in your package.json

```
"start": "electron --enable-transparent-visuals ."
```

---

EDIT 2 :
To make it works out of the box, use this repo : https://gitlab.com/doom-fr/electron-transparency-demo

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/doom-fr/electron-transparency-demo
cd electron-transparency-demo
npm install
npm start
# or npm run startWithTransparentOption
# or npm run startWithAllOptions
```

for me works with `npm start` and  `npm run startWithTransparentOption`

---

EDIT 3 :
Please have a look also to [@Thalinda Bandara answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53538215/cant-succeed-in-making-transparent-window-in-electron-javascript/63154668#63154668) :
It might be interresting (not tested but already seen it elsewhere).

Answer (score 5):

I found a way to get it working! Try creating your window 10 milliseconds after Electron's ready, like this:

```
app.on('ready', function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        createWindow();
    }, 10);
});
```

Instead of: `app.on('ready', createWindow);`

I found  it from this Github post: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2170#issuecomment-361549395

Also, you need to keep these command line flags for it to work: `--enable-transparent-visuals --disable-gpu`

---

<s>Unfortunately Electron doesn't support transparent windows on linux.</s>

I have actually tried a bunch of things to get it working but nothing has worked yet.

Source: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8532#issuecomment-306383343

Comment: [Here](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window) it is said that it works (with some limitations, but it should work)

Comment: @doom Hi, sorry I thought it wasn't possible but I dug a little further and it turns out it was! Please see my edited answer

Comment: It's a good idea, but it does not work. Still having black background.

Comment: @doom Does it have a error message or is it just black? Also make sure you still have these command line flags `--enable-transparent-visuals --disable-gpu`.

Comment: @doom Also I think it might be because your using electron nightly, try installing version `3.0.10` with: `npm i -D electron@latest`. I know you said that you tried this version in your post but can you try my fix for this version as well?

Comment: @doom Ok, does it have a error message or is it just black?

Comment: in 4.0.0, there's a error about font. In 1.5.0 (which is the first version with the bug), no error.

Comment: That's odd. I'm using v3.0.10 and it's working for me with my fix

Comment: OK. What's your OS ? Which version ?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 using electron v3.0.10. I run my app with `electron . --enable-transparent-visuals --disable-gpu`.

Comment: @doom I just read https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2170#issuecomment-372108061 and it seems like 10 millisecond might be too short. Could you try my fix but with a 100 millisecond delay?

Comment: it is already done. Look at my test repo. Maybe you could try to clone it for local test.

Comment: @doom I just tried it again and it didn't work this time :(. I'm not sure why but I'll keep trying

Comment: You have tried again my repo or you test files ? What does `./node_modules/.bin/electron --version` give now ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @doom I tried your repo first then mine but I'm still running the same version v3.0.10

Comment: @doom For some reason when I run it without `--enable-transparent-visuals --disable-gpu` it works. Can you try this as well?

Comment: I have read somewhere that effectively it is not needed since version ?? . Already tested with no effect. Have retested it now in nightly, 3.0.9, 3.0.10 without `--enable-transparent-visuals --disable-gpu`, but it is still not working.

Comment: Which graphic card do you have ? `sudo lshw -short` gives me : `/0/100/1/0                        display        GK107 [GeForce GT 630 OEM]`

Comment: @doom I have: `/0/100/2  display  Intel Corporation`. But I think if Electron doesn't really support it on Linux then it's probably better to wait. It's odd though since it works on my computer consistenly now

Comment: [here](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window) it is said that `--enable-transparent-visuals --disable-gpu` is only needed for some Nvidia graphic cards, so normal it works without on your machine.  In 1.4.16, it seems to work very well. Think we have to wait for my issue.

Comment: It didn't work with 10 but surely did work with 100ms

Answer (score 2):

if any one getting this error with new version you have disable or undocked developer tools then you will be able to succeed with transparent window

```
win.webContents.openDevTools({mode:'undocked'})
```

Answer (score 1):

BrowserWindow {transparent: true} works if you don't open devTools i.e. don't add

`YourNewBrowserWindow.webContents.openDevTools()` to the main.js (or electron.js) script

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the white window disappears after redrawing it (after a resize for example).
In my code I wrote this:

```
function createWindow() {
  const size = screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;

  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: size.width - 1,
    height: size.height - 1,
    minWidth: 260,
    minHeight: 360,
    frame: false,
    transparent: true,
    webPreferences: {
      // ...
    },
  });

  win.setBackgroundColor("#000000");
  win.webContents.setFrameRate(60);

  // Set maximized size
  win.maximize(); // change window size -> redrawing
  win.setFullScreen(true); // change window property -> redrawing

  // ...

}
```

I added this too:

```
app.on('ready', () => setTimeout(createWindow, 300));
```