# Make a non-frameless Electron window have a transparent background

Tags: electron

I'm looking to make an Electron window have a transparent background, but keep its window chrome.

I used the following:

```
  const previewWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    x: 1000,
    y: 100,
    transparent: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });
```

I also set the following CSS on the body of the page being displayed in the window:

```
background: transparent;
```

I also tried `background: none`.

The window still have the default white background.

Is it possible to have a transparent window in Electron without it being frameless?

Comment: Hi, creating transparent windows is difficult and depends on your OS and graphics card. Can you include what OS you are aiming for? Also check out this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53538215/cant-succeed-in-making-transparent-window-in-electron-javascript/53538807#53538807)