# Electron - Make transparent window with no background

Tags: javascript, electron

So I'm experiencing issue when I'm trying to make a window transparent. I made `tranparent: true, frame: false` but it doesn't really work. It removes the frame and stuff but doesn't do what I want till the end. I want it to be like really transparent. What I get is a: [image: Frameless window but not transparent] frameless window which is not transparent.

Help would be appreciated. Some code:

**main.js**

```
// main.js

// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const { maxHeaderSize } = require('http')
const path = require('path')

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: maxHeaderSize,
    height: maxHeaderSize,
    transparent:true,
    frame: false
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('bodycam.html')
  

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
app.whenReady().then(() => {

  function onAppReady() {
    createWindow()

    app.on('activate', function () {
      // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
      // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
      if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
    })
  }

  setTimeout(onAppReady, 300)
  
})

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
```

**some part of the code (that affects *html body*) from style.css (that's being linked with bodycam.html)**

```
body {
    margin: 0px auto; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    font-family: 'Share Tech Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @mplungjan hi. Um I'd like to know if my question is clear enough. If it is not, I could explain more what I would like to get as a result of the code.

Comment: Did you check other questions, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53538215/cant-succeed-in-making-transparent-window-in-electron-javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why you are facing this issue

In your case, you are facing this issue because you are trying to define the size of the window from the `maxHeaderSize` value, wich comes from the [http Node API](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_maxheadersize). And this... Actually makes no sense. The value of `maxHEaderSize` is probably **way bigger** than the size of your screen. Electron seems to be suffering when creating a transparent window that big.

### How to fix

You just need to remove that crazy value when creating your BrowserWindow. For example :

```js
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    transparent: true,
    frame: false,
})
```

If you want to set your window at the same size of your screen, you can use the `fullscreen` option :

```js
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    transparent: true,
    frame: false,
    fullscreen: true,
})
```

Finally, if you want your user to be able to "click throught the window", you probably will be interested in the [setIgnoreMouseEvents](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetignoremouseeventsignore-options) method :

```js
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    transparent: true,
    frame: false,
    fullscreen: true,
})
mainWindow.setIgnoreMouseEvents(true)
```