# How to make a transparent loading GIF window in Electron?

Tags: electron, window, loading, transparency, gif

My current code:

```js
const loadingWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  show: false,
  icon: require('./forge.config.js').packagerConfig.icon,
  width: 80,
  height: 80,
  frame: false,
  transparent: true,
  resizable: false,
})

loadingWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => loadingWindow.show())

loadingWindow.loadFile('loading.gif')
```

You can view the loading GIF from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA5r1.gif), you may see an opaque background, that's added by browsers, the GIF itself is transparent.

But when start the app, it shows:

[image]

How to make it transparent?

OS: Windows 10
Electron: v13.1.7

P.S. Before posting this question, I've searched through the related questions on SO, but didn't find one that involves GIF.

Comment: What OS are you using? Transparent windows are buggy on Linux. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53538215/cant-succeed-in-making-transparent-window-in-electron-javascript/63154668#63154668

Comment: @Joshua I only tested on Windows 10.

Comment: As far as I can see everything looks fine, is there any other code that isn't included that could possibly be affecting this? If you create a small test app with the bare minimum code, does it still break? Can you also see if it works with a transparent image too?

Comment: I'm seeing your second image when viewing the imgur link. Is that expected?

Comment: @pushkin Yes, that is expected, I've updated the description to reflect that.